# Visual Studio C# to MS Access Connection Failure

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2015

I have been working on this a while.  I'm attempting to add values to an access     DB through a custom program.  I don't have any syntax errors or anything that I can see wrong, but i'm a rookie.  Any help would be much appreciated.
I have some dirty code in there I was messing around with, but commented it out.  Please help!  Thanks guys and gals.

I'm on AMD Win 10 
Visual Studio 2015
Access 2016

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class frmNewClient : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();


        public frmNewClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cmdClientInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        string CompanyName = txtCCOMPANYNAME.Text;
        string ContactName = txtCCONTACTNAME.Text;
        string Street = txtCSTREET.Text;
        string City = txtCCITY.Text;
        string State = txtCSTATE.Text;
        string ZIP = txtCZIP.Text;
        string Phone1 = txtCPHONE1.Text;
        string Phone2 = txtCPHONE2.Text;
        string Email = txtCEMAIL.Text;
        string Notes = txtCNOTES.Text;
        connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\\lafiammadb.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT Into Clients(CompanyName, ContactName, Street, City, State, ZIP, Phone1, Phone2, Email, Notes)" + "values(@CompanyName, @ContactName, @Street, @City, @State, @ZIP, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Email, @Notes)", connect);
        if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = CompanyName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactName", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = ContactName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = Street;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = City;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = State;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ZIP", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = ZIP;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone1", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = Phone1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone2", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = Phone2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = Email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Notes", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = Notes;
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added To Database");
                txtCCOMPANYNAME.Text = "";
                txtCCONTACTNAME.Text = "";
                txtCSTREET.Text = "";
                txtCCITY.Text = "";
                txtCSTATE.Text = "";
                txtCZIP.Text = "";
                txtCPHONE1.Text = "";
                txtCPHONE2.Text = "";
                txtCEMAIL.Text = "";
                txtCNOTES.Text = "";

            }
            catch (Exception expe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(expe.Source);
                connect.Close();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");

        }
        //connect.Open();


        //OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", CompanyName);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", ContactName);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", Street);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIP", ZIP);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", Phone1);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", Phone2);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes);
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        //OleDbCommand CmdSql = new OleDbCommand("Insert into [clients](Company Name, Contact Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Phone1, Phone2, Email, Notes)



    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Slappywag:- `I don't have any syntax errors or anything that I can see wrong`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
```

You are checking that the connection is Open or not but at no point you are actually opening your connection. You need to `Open` your connection before checking it. You can try like this:

```
if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    connect.Open();
}
```

**On a side note:**

You can think of using the `using` statament as well when dealing with connections.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This line is giving you the problem `if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)`. What you really want to do is to check if the connection is closed and then open it so:

```
if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
  connect.Open();
  //Do Some work
}
```

However I would recommend you make the use of you `using` block this will ensure the object is disposed correctly.

From **MSDN**

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

```
using(OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
  connect.Open();
  //Do some work
}// Here it will automatically call Dispose();
```

As [OleDbConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class implements IDisposable. So you can use `Dispose()` method directly and won't be required to call `connect.Close();`